# Use of the parameter 'status' to exit

Tags: php

According to the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php) to exit:

> If status is an integer, that value will be used as the exit status and not printed.

This made ​​me very confused. What is the difference between a `exit();` and a `exit(1);`? What are the use cases? How should I choose? On what occasions? How php manages this state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between `exit();` and `exit(1);` is, that the former sets the [exit status](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_status) of the process executing your PHP script to `0` and the latter sets it to `1`.

An exit status of `0` usually means that the process finished sucessfully. No error occurred.

An exit status of `1` to `254` usually is used to signal that the process was aborted because some kind of error occurred. What error a specific exit status means is up to your PHP script.

Parent processes can use the exit statuses returned by child processes to decide how to continue, e.g. whether they should exit too, or retry, or execute another child process, or whatever.

Answer (score 3):

There's a numeric return code that can be read by the OS/the shell/the process that has invoked your PHP script. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_status

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's only useful if the script is being executed from the command line or another program is executing it, through the web server it's pointless.

Answer (score 0):

it like the return code in C++, when usually the program returns 0 when everything is done successfully, negative when some error has occurred and positive number depending where that code can be used.

but in general as it is already said in previous answers, if the script won't be called from another script or program it doesn't make much sense what to return